# srand(time(NULL)) "Function 'srand' could not be resolved."

Tags: c++, srand

I have been trying to debug this problem for a while and quite honestly, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Why is there a syntax error?

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <time.h>;
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <stdlib.h>;
using namespace std;


class Problem3 {
    public:
        bool isPrime(long double num) {
            srand(time(NULL));
            return 0;
        }
};
```

The error I'm getting is,

> "Function 'srand' could not be resolved."

- I'm well aware now that I don't need the semi-colons after 'include' statements
- I'm using Eclipse CDT along with MinGW as my compiler

**How I resolved the problem:**

It had to do with the MinGW compiler I was using. Switching over to Visual Studio solved the problem.

Comment: The fact that you didn't show the complete error message demonstrates that you are not accustomed to reading it.

Comment: time() returns a time_t object. srand() expects an unsigned int. see the problem?

Comment: @MarcB Even if the types mismatch, the nested function calls don't generate a syntax error (but a semantic one).

Comment: @OP You are in the serious need of re-reading **carefully** a beginner C or C++ tutorial. Getting wrong a simple include indicates that you are not prepared for writing anything practically complex.

Comment: `srand` should only be called once during program startup. Otherwise you'll get less than random values.

Comment: @paddy, the error was "Function 'srand' could not be resolved"

Comment: @Haque1 That's not a syntax error, that's a linking error which is very different than what your title might suggest. Make sure Eclipse isn't invoking g++ with `-nodefaultlibs`.

Comment: @greatwolf how do I do that?

Comment: there is already question in SO check if that helps [Eclipse Method could not be resolved in a simple program C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556274/function-srand-could-not-be-solve-im-using-ubuntu-os-and-eclipse)

Comment: @pinkpanther I tried code in Visual Studio and it works so it's most likely a problem with the compiler

Comment: @Haque1 yeah, problem with your ide configuration for specific...any ways you got your problem solved....that's great

Comment: If switching from MinGW to Visual Studio solves problems (instead of creating new ones, which is the VS norm), then you are almost certainly doing something fishy or non-standard. Or maybe you are simply compiling/linking the code incorrectly in MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` at the end of the `#include` directives are the problem in your code. `#include` directives don't need (wrong to place indeed) semicolons at the end unlike `C++` statements.

```
[Warning] extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
```

It seems any character after `>` in the directive causes this error/warning.

```
          #include<iostream>a   //error
```

Change to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


class Problem3 {
    public:
        bool isPrime(long double num) {
            srand(time(NULL));
            return 0;
        }
};

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello Main";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the linker issue:

One suggestion is `C++` expects types to be explicitly casted between types (more than `C`). So, use a cast to convert `time_t` which is returned by the `time` to `unsigned int` which is the input parameter type of `srand`. (And of course this might not be the problem with linker error)

Instead of using `stdlib.h`, try using `<cstdlib>`, try if it helps. Because it uses namespace.

Apart from that, I have seen this snippet [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand). Use that pattern if it helps.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    srand(time(0)); //use current time as seed for random generator
    int random_variable = rand();
    cout << "Random value on [0 " << RAND_MAX << "]: " 
              << random_variable << '\n';
}
```

there is already question in SO check if that helps [Eclipse Method could not be resolved in a simple program C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556274/function-srand-could-not-be-solve-im-using-ubuntu-os-and-eclipse)

[Never use time() to initialize srand().](http://csl.sublevel3.org/c++/).

**EDIT:**

Now it seems many people got this kind of problem. I found a question  [How do I fix Eclipse CDT Error “Function 'isdigit' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755547/how-do-i-fix-eclipse-cdt-error-function-isdigit-could-not-be-resolved-with-a). He is facing the same problem. The asker suggested a work around to this in his question edit.

Quoted from that question:

> I now believe this to be a Code Analysis problem. A better solution is
> to edit the Code Analysis options to make "Function could not be
> resolved" be a warning instead of an error. That way you can see the
> warnings in Problems view, but continue to work. If the function is
> REALLY missing, the compiler will tell you! I also have a new theory,
> that the problem is with the Code Analyzer following symlinks, because
> all of the "missing" functions are in symlinked include files. Would
> love any input on this theory.

Hope that points to solve the problem.

Comment: There is a main method, I just didn't post it here. The problem I'm having is in the isPrime() function so that's what I posted

Comment: MinGW. Also if it helps, I'm developing in Eclipse CDT

Comment: @Haque1 see the edit in my answer, use that link to solve your problem.

Comment: Linker errors? The link posted discourages time() as seed when using random number generation in several processes launched at the same time. There is nothing regarding any linker errors there. Nor does it seem related to the question.

Comment: @Lundin thanks :) I will definitely edit my answer to improve this...and I'm currently searching that.....

Comment: but I saw this statement `So the linker is giving you a hard time? Most likely a library and your host program are using conflicting C++ runtime libraries.` that's why I've posted the link

Answer (score 3):

`;` should not be there after `#include`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

`#include` files shoule not end with `;`